# AEM dispatcher rule precedence

Tags: aem, dispatcher

I am new to AEM dispatcher configurations

Was going through the configurations and could see the rules as below

```
  /0081 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.infinity.json*" }

  /0082 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.tidy.json*"     }

  /0083 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.sysview.xml*"   }

  /0084 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.docview.json*"  }

  /0085 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.docview.xml*"   }

  /0086 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.*[0-9].json*"   }

  /0087 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.feed.xml*"      }
```

Can some one help me understand what this starting /four numbers mean?

```
**/0087** { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.feed.xml*"      }
```

Do we have any precendence order or can we give some random number if we need to add a new rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are evaluated in the order that they appear.  Think of those starting 4 numbers as an identifier--an ID.  That's about all it is.

More info here:

- https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/dispatcher-cache-rule-priority/qaq-p/164316?profile.language=en&pageRefresh=true